# Can't include more than one input in webapp2 form

Tags: python, html, webapp2

I tried adding an input (text) field to a working example (https://realpython.com/python-web-applications/), and it broke. My Python code is:

```
import webapp2

def convert_temp(cel_temp):
    if cel_temp == "":
        return ""
    try:
        far_temp = float(cel_temp) * 9 / 5 + 32
        far_temp = round(far_temp, 3)  # round to three decimal places
        return str(far_temp)
    except ValueError:  # user entered non-numeric temperature
        return "invalid input"

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        cel_temp = self.request.get("cel_temp")
        far_temp = convert_temp(cel_temp)
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
        self.response.write("""
        <html>
        <head><title>Temperature Converter</title></head>
        <body>
          <form action="/" method="get">
            <fieldset>
            Celsius temperature: <input type="text" name="cel_temp" value={}><br>
            Dummy: <input type="text" name="dummy" value={}>                        
            <input type="submit" value="Convert"><br>
            Fahrenheit temperature: {}
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>""".format(cel_temp, far_temp))

routes = [('/', MainPage)]
my_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, debug=True)
```

The new line is the one beginning with "Dummy". The code worked until I put that in, now it throws an internal server error. I'm not getting any clues from looking at HTML doco, so I'm not sure what to try from here.

Comment: Nb. The <fieldset>, </fieldset> tags weren't in the original example. I put them in to see if they could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way `format` works. You need to supply the correct number of arguments at the end, so that you match all the `{}` with one parameter each. I didn't test it, but this should work, note the empty string as the third argument which should match the third `{}`:

```
  self.response.write("""
        <html>
        <head><title>Temperature Converter</title></head>
        <body>
          <form action="/" method="get">
            <fieldset>
            Celsius temperature: <input type="text" name="cel_temp" value={}><br>
            Dummy: <input type="text" name="dummy" value={}>                        
            <input type="submit" value="Convert"><br>
            Fahrenheit temperature: {}
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>""".format(cel_temp, far_temp, "")
```